# POST request node js

Tags: node.js, curl, post

Okay so I have struggled with this for quite a while. I have a curl command that are supposed to work. Since I'm not familiar with curl I "translated" it to node. But it doesn't work. Here is the curl line.

```
    curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'token: XXXXXX' -d '[ \ 
   { \ 
     "id": "eh", \ 
     \ 
     "kind": "goods", \ 
     "data": {} \ 
   } \ 
 ]' 'http://localhost:5000/api/article'
```

When I have translated it to node it looks like this:

```
var request = require('request');

var dataString = '[ \ 
   { \ 
     "id": "eh", \ 
     \ 
     "kind": "goods", \ 
     "data": {} \ 
   } \ 
 ]';

var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/article',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

The error message I get is

> throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is the output of your code? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');

Comment: Which line does that error appear on!?¿

Comment: _http_outgoing.js:456
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

Comment: Think i solved it, look at my answer now

Comment: Siriously? Are you going to just let it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `request` docs:

body - entity body for PATCH, POST and PUT requests. Must be a Buffer, String or ReadStream. If json is true, then body must be a JSON-serializable object.

So you have two options here.

If this is the body you want to send:

```
var data = [{
    "id": "eh",
    "kind": "goods",
    "data": {}
}];
```

You can do pass the `json: true` option:

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/article',
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    json: true
};
```

Or you can stringify your data array before sending it:

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/article',
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)    
};
```

Comment: Yea i know just straight up coppied it, I have removed all the backslashes in the acctual code.

Comment: Hmmm. This removed all the error messages but still it doesn't get posted successfully. When I try to "GET" the article and console log it i just get "null"

Comment: You asked how to perform a POST request, i answered you. Your problem now looks to be related to the way you save the article to DB rather than the request. Did you check at DB if the article is stored?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't answer, but thank you. I needed this part "json: true". Also I had a backend problem but I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = [  
   { 
     "id": "eh",  
     "kind": "goods", 
     "data": {} 
   } 
 ];

var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/article',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

//request(options, callback);
enter code here
 request.post({url:options.url, formData: :options.body}, callback);
```